# Script for Installing missing packages via dpkg-query

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I've got a script working to echo out the packages missing in the command line but would like a option to add in control for install the missing applications. What would the best way go to doing this? apt-get install $tmp?

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Checking server for missing packages..."
tmp=$(dpkg-query -W -f='${Package} ${Status} \n' apache2 openssh-server php5 \
php5-cli php5-xsl php5-imap php5-curl | grep "no package found")

if [[ $tmp =~ "no package found" ]]
then
echo "working"
apt-get install $tmp
else
echo "foo"
fi
```

I've tried to add a loop into it but not getting the output from $tmp

Thanks

Comment: Could be. You might need sudo for apt-get install.

Answer (score 1):

apt-get won't complain if you name packages already installed on your system.
Given this fact, I wouldn't bother trying to filter out already installed packages and just use the following one-liner.

```
apt-get install apache2 openssh-server php5 php5-cli php5-xsl php5-imap php5-curl
```

You might want to add -qy switches to run quietly and without beeing asked any question.